# I want to scroll use only button on scrollify

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm using a scroll animation through the "[scrollify](https://projects.lukehaas.me/scrollify/#home)".

i want limit any scroll function.

i want to scroll only use button click scrolling, but not use touch scroll and mouse scroll.

if it's hard, expedient also good. Is there aother way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think touch events are currently not supported. But for the mousewheel you could do:

JQuery:

```
$('body').bind("mousewheel", function() {
    return false;
});
```